# Prove that the cyclic nature of isomorphic groups are preserved

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof, group-isomorphism

In my textbook, the proof has been done quite in a mainstream fashion. Which goes like the following:

Let $\phi:G \rightarrow G'$ be an isomorphism. We are to show that if either one be cyclic, then the other is too .

Using the fact that the mapping is surjective, for an arbitrary element $b \in G' $,    $\exists$ some $a^r \in G$ such that $\phi (a^r) =b=\{\phi(a)\}^r$. Now, it proceeds to state that every element in $G'$ can be written in such a fashion, implying the cyclic nature of it. Further, in a similar way, it shows the converse.

My question is, why they simply did not use the fact that $o(a)=o(\phi(a))$ [ $\phi$ being an isomorphism] , in conjunction with the fact that they have the same cardinality [ the mapping being a bijection] and $o(a)=$ The order of $G$ ? In fact, the whole thing seems just to be a corollary of above. Again, the converse can be proven simply using the fact the $\phi^{-1}$ is an isomorphism from $G'$ to $G$.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: The proof given in the book, as well as the proof that you suggest, are both valid ways to get to the point. They both work.

Comment: I am not really comfortable with these proof writing, yet. So I decided to ask it here. Thank You!!!

Comment: $o(a)$ need not be the order of $G$. Take $a=e$. Also, what about $o(a)=\infty$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have omitted the fact that I am considering $a$ as the generator. Pretty evident. As far as infinite order is concerned, we can show that there cannot be an $m$, s.t $a^m=e$, thus arriving at a contradiction.

Comment: Pretty evident is this anyway, yes. There are many proofs that being cyclic is an isomorphism invariant.